# Function Traversing Through An Array of Json Object needs to return one object

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

So I am not the best at writing functions so I am having a hard time wrapping a head around this. So I am trying to create a function that traverses through array of objects, and stops once it reads the name that is given it must return the number of the that person.

```
const array = [{name: 'Ann', phone: '575.580.1400', role: 'Developer'},
               {name: 'Ben', phone: '575.641.4041', role: 'Manager'},
               {name: 'Clara', phone: '512.717.5690', role: 'Developer'}];

const getNumber = (person, book ) => {
      for (var x of book ) {
          if( x == person) {
             return number;}
     return ('Not found'); 
     }
}
```

I know I am missing how to call in the number, but I just can't think of how to do it.

Comment: `x` is an object from your array, you can access the name key using `x.name`, same with the number: `x.number`

Comment: let foundPerson = array.filter((person) => person.name == name);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to access the key inside the object and  `return ('Not found');` is not in the right place. Secondly use `===` instead of `==`.In your code if the function will return in the fist iteration only. Because if you search for `Clara` and in the `if` condition `Ann` will not be equal to `Clara` so it will return `Not Found` and will not iterate the remaining array

```js
const array = [{
    name: 'Ann',
    phone: '575.580.1400',
    role: 'Developer'
  },
  {
    name: 'Ben',
    phone: '575.641.4041',
    role: 'Manager'
  },
  {
    name: 'Clara',
    phone: '512.717.5690',
    role: 'Developer'
  }
];

const getNumber = (person, book) => {
  for (var x of book) {
    if (x.name === person) {
      return x.phone;
    }
  }
  return ('Not found');
}
console.log(getNumber('Clara', array))
```

Alternatively you can also use array methods like `find` or `filter`

```js
const array = [{
    name: 'Ann',
    phone: '575.580.1400',
    role: 'Developer'
  },
  {
    name: 'Ben',
    phone: '575.641.4041',
    role: 'Manager'
  },
  {
    name: 'Clara',
    phone: '512.717.5690',
    role: 'Developer'
  }
];

const num = array.find(item => item.name === 'Clara').phone;
console.log(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code helps to iterate through a JSON object and print the required value. You can use the required conditions in IF and print the desired values accordingly.

```
 var json = [{name: 'Ann', phone: '575.580.1400', role: 'Developer'},
           {name: 'Ben', phone: '575.641.4041', role: 'Manager'},
           {name: 'Clara', phone: '512.717.5690', role: 'Developer'}];

for (var key in json) {
   if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
   if(json[key].name=='Ben')
      
      console.log(json[key].phone);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

I am using some instead of foreach or other loops. some() method executes the callback function once for each element present in the array until it finds the one where callback returns a truthy value.

```
const getNumber = (person, book ) => { 
      let pnumber;
      book.some((item) => {
        if(item.name.toLowerCase()===person.toLowerCase()){
            pnumber = item.phone;
            return true;
             }
         })
      return pnumber ? pnumber: "Not Found" ;
     }
```

you can call it this way

```
getNumber('clara',array)
"512.717.5690"

getNumber('ben1',array)
"Not Found"
```